# What does \fi means?

Tags: code, definition

I want to know the meaning of `\fi` in LaTeX. I don't understand the use. And don't find an easy definition online.

Comment: `\if...\fi` ... a usual way in scripts of conditional tests. `\fi` is just the reverse of `\if` and can be found in script languages as well as in `bash` etc. as well, and indicates the end of the `\if` test, similar to `case...esac`